# awk or sed: how to modify based on previous and next lines

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have a file like below

```
* jhasjdhjh

sample1

* oioieoirer

sample2

* jsdhfjhdf
 * ppppppp
sample3
 * iouiuiouo
```

I want it to be

```
* jhasjdhjh

 * sample

* oioieoirer

 * sampel2

* jsdhfjhdf
 * ppppppp
     * sample3
 * iouiuiouo
```

So sample1, sample2 we want to add  `*`  (space asteric space) since the above line and below line have `*` (asteric space)

sample3 we want to add        * (5 spaces and asteric)   because the previous line has (space and asteric)

So I have to check the previous line and the next line based on their asteric and then i have to decide what to put on the current line.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: cyrus. This question  is related to previous lines and next lines status which i dont have any clue. I use sed to replace a specific text, but not comparitive replacing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if data in 'd', try gnu sed,

```
 sed -Ez 's/(\s*\*\s*\S+\s*\n)(\S+)/\1  *\2/g ' d
```